# Issue with getting battery capacity from DS2782 fuel gauge IC

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, bms, fuel-gauge

I am using a 5100 mAh Li-ion battery pack connected to the load setup which has a DS2782 IC on board. I flashed the fuel gauge parameters into these registers (address 60h-7Ah). These values are supposed to be written into the EEPROM automatically.

These are the values flashed to algorithm

[image]

We are able to read back these values from the register. We were also able to verify that aging scaler and accumulated current register are updated in the EEPROM.

The issue I am facing is that even though I flashed the fuel gauge parameters into the in-built EEPROM, when reading from the RARC (Remaining active relative capacity) and RSRC (Remaining standby relative capacity) registers, I am getting value as 0. Not quite sure what is wrong.

These are the logs.

```
I (1629754) DS2782: DS2782 voltage read success
I (1629754) I2C: Voltage VALUE is:3.947920
I (1629754) DS2782: DS2782  current read success
I (1629754) DS2782: Current REG value1: 0x0h
I (1629754) DS2782: Current REG value2: 0x10h
I (1629764) DS2782: Current RAW value: 10
I (1629764) I2C: Current VALUE is: +2.500000 ma
I (1629774) DS2782: DS2782  Param read success
I (1629774) I2C: RSNSP VALUE 0x64h
I (1629784) DS2782: DS2782  Param read success
I (1629784) I2C: VCHG REG value: 0xd5h
I (1629794) I2C: VCHG value: 4.157760
I (1629794) DS2782: DS2782  Param read success
I (1629804) I2C: IMIN REG value: 0x1fh
I (1629804) I2C: IMIN value: 155.000000
I (1629814) DS2782: DS2782 read success
I (1629814) DS2782: Capacity raw value:0
I (1629824) I2C: RARC:0 %
I (1629824) DS2782: DS2782 read success
I (1629824) DS2782: Capacity raw value:0
I (1629834) I2C: RSRC:0 %
I (1629834) DS2782: DS2782  Param read success
I (1629844) I2C: Aging scalar: 80
I (1629844) DS2782: DS2782  Param read success
I (1629854) I2C: control REG VALUE 0x0h
I (1629854) DS2782: DS2782  Param read success
I (1629864) I2C: status REG VALUE 0x61h
I (1629864) DS2782: DS2782  FULL cap read success
I (1629864) DS2782: FULL CAP REG value1: 0x7fh
I (1629874) DS2782: FULL CAP REG value2: 0xcah
I (1629884) I2C: FULL CAP REG VALUE 0x7fcah
I (1629884) I2C: FULL CAP  VALUE 29474
I (1629884) DS2782: DS2782  RAAC read success
I (1629894) DS2782: RAAC REG value1: 0x0h
I (1629894) DS2782: RAAC REG value2: 0x0h
I (1629904) I2C: RAAC REG VALUE 0x0h
I (1629904) I2C: RAAC  VALUE 0
```

For initial first time charge, do we need to complete one charge cycle for DS2782 to show RARC and RSRC.

How to know state of the battery if replaced with a different battery?

Any help would be appreciated.

We followed the following link to calculate the parameters:
https://www.stg-maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/app-notes/3/3584.html

I am attaching a snippet of the schematic and the values that I am flashing for reference.
[image]